# How to check if word is in array then return the matched word

Tags: php, regex, arrays, filter, compare

**Question 1**

I'm using the following to check for bad words from some input element, and i want to tell the user which word on their text is not allowed. How do i get that specific word or words from the array that matched it? And how when user entered more than one bad word this only detects the first word and ignores the rest.

**Question 2**.

How do i ignore lower and upper cases, this code doesn't recognize **"John"** and **"john"** as the same thing. I don't know if this is a regex job. Please reccomend another way if this is weak.
**PHP**

```
$BadWords = array("James", "June", "Jane");
if (in_array($comment, $BadWords)){
    echo 'No way... that is not allowed lol...';
}
```

**Question 3** (*Speed*)

Say i have around 2000 words to compare a word against, which way is the best to do this process faster without misuse resources while taking into account that filtering bad words is just an example as this is not limited to checking bad words and at all cases not considering databases.

Thanks.

Comment: Definitely not a _regex_ job. Say the foul word is _rascal_ on your array and if the user typed _damn rascal_ then your code fails.

Comment: Think practically, you just mentioned there maybe 2000 words, now for eg. in those 2000 words, there are 10 bad words, would you be showing only 1 not allowed word, have him correct it and submit and then show the next?

Comment: What do you suggest i do?

Comment: @user3109875 Based on user experience, it's best you submit them together saying something like 'Following words are not allowed in comments: ' and then the list. So then they know all that not allowed and have it corrected in one go?

Comment: That's what i want to do but i don't know how to code that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**`array_search`**](https://www.php.net/array_search) to get the matched words from the key

```
 <?php
$comment="James";
$BadWords = array("James", "June", "Jane");
$bwords = array_map('strtoupper',$BadWords);
if (in_array(strtoupper($comment), $bwords)){
    $k=array_search($comment,$bwords);
    echo $BadWords[$k]."\n";
    echo 'No way... that is not allowed lol...';
}
```

Comment: I like this, can we make it not case sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

Combining both the above answers, this will detect if there is more than one badword and also if it's concatenated with any other string:

```
$comment="James junexyz";
$BadWords = array("James", "June", "Jane");
foreach($BadWords as $k=>$v){
    $pos = stripos($comment,$v);
    if($pos!==false){
        echo $v. ' is not allowed'.'<br>';
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/DRCtnN)**

Comment: Yes this dies check for more than one word, but for_each returns more than one reply to the user. As in, if two bad words are found. You will have "James is not alllowed. junexyz is not allowed." Please check that.

Comment: @user3109875 What if the user does enter multiple bad words? You would want to show only 1 at a time? Use a `break;` after the `echo`.

Comment: @user3109875, You will never get a perfect answer if you go on editing your question. Sit down, relax, take your time.. prepare your question with all your requirements and then post it !

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet it will work lower and upper cases

```
$comment="James"; // 'james'
$BadWords = array("James", "June", "Jane");
$lowerCap = array_map('strtolower', $BadWords);
  if (in_array(strtolower($comment), $lowerCap)){
    $k=array_search($comment,$lowerCap );
    echo $BadWords[$k]."\n";
    echo 'No way... that is not allowed lol...';
}
```